# Stone-Čech Compactification of the Natural numbers

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am trying to prove that if $U$ is contained in the Stone-Čech Compactification of the natural number ($\beta N$) that the closure of $U$ is open.

I have a really hard time with even understanding what the Stone-Čech Compactification is, so I can't even start this problem. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, it will be difficult to study $\beta \mathbb N$ without first understanding its construction.  For this I would recommend the construction via ultrafilters - for discrete spaces it will be easiest (even if you currently know nothing about ultrafilters).  Then there are several equivalent characterizations of $\beta X$ you should explore. Depending on the application, one of these may be particularly convenient.

Answer (score 4):

A basic (perhaps defining) property of $\beta$ tells us:

> Let $X$ be completely regular Hausdorff and let $Y$ be compact Hausdorff.  If $f : X \to Y$ is continuous, then there is a unique continuous extension $f^\beta : \beta X \to Y$.

So, let $U \subset \mathbb N$.  Let $f : \mathbb N \to \{0,1\}$ be the characteristic function of $U$.  Examine what it means for the extension $f^\beta$.

Comment: Once you have proved that $\beta X$ exists, it is usually preferable to study it using a universal mapping property like this, and not by trying to understand spaces of ultrafilters or something.

Answer (score 3):

> **Lemma 1 (see the [Engelking's book](http://books.google.com.hk/books/about/General_topology.html?hl=zh-CN&id=h4FsAAAAMAAJ) Corollary 3.6.5): For every open and closed subset $A$ of a Tychonoff space $X$ the closure $\overline{A}$ of $A$ in $\beta X$ is open and closed.**

**Proof:** Notice that $U \cap N$ is not empty, since $U$ is open and $N$ is dense in $\beta X$. Moreover, $U \cap N$ is open and closed in $N$, then we apply the Lemma 1 to conclude that $\overline{U\cap N}$ is open in $\beta X$. Finally, note that $\overline{U}=\overline{U\cap N}$, since $N$ is dense in $\beta N$. Thus we conclude that $\overline{U}$ is open in $\beta X$.

Answer (score 3):

Like those who have answered previously (GEdgar and Paul), I'll assume you intended $U$ to be a subset of $\mathbb N$, even though the question assumes only $U\subseteq\beta\mathbb N$.  (If one takes the question literally, the result is just false.)  Once you see how $\beta\mathbb N$ is constructed using ultrafilters, it will be easy to check that, if $\mathbb  N$ is partitioned into two pieces, then the closures of those pieces constitute a partition of $\beta\mathbb N$.  In particular, $(\beta\mathbb N)-\overline U=\overline{N-U}$ is closed, and therefore $\overline U$ is open.

Comment: I don't understand why it is possible that $U⊆βX$ is open but $\overline{U}$ is not. An open subset of $βX$ can be identified with an ideal of subsets of $X$. It is closed if and only if there is a maximal element. Dually, a closed subset of $βX$ can be identified with a filter of subsets of $X$ and it is open if it is principal. Under this point of view, the closure of an open subset seen as an ideal is the filter of all the subsets containing all the elements of the ideal. But then there is a minimal element, right? It is the union of all the elements of the filter.

Comment: Ah, I just realized that this is because $U$ is not *open* in the question. It is just a subset of $βℕ$.